# iPhone App for External Microphone

Tags: iphone, mac-appstore, microphone

Is there a special app needed on my iPhone XR for the video camera to sync an **external microphone**?

I have all the TRS/Lightning connections correct, but no voice is recording with the video.

Comment: I can related to the frustration, but are you specifically looking for an app, or is it an extension of *external mic not being detected in videos* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no special app needed.

It sounds like you're using some kind of adapter/dongle for converting between the Lightning interface and a simple TRS. You do not mention what dongle or microphone, you're using.

It sounds likely that you are using incorrect cables. The TRS plug comes in two versions - the CTIA version used on iPhone (and most Android phones), and the OMTP version used on some Android phones and especially older equipment. If you have the incorrect verison, you'll get no voice recorded.

Comment: I called Apple support, they confirmed, no app is needed.

Then, I finally received support from the manufacturer. He told me to plug the mic into the headphone jack on my wireless receiver and see if that works. It did work. He said some manufacturers will make connections proprietary in order to force users to buy their replacement cables and adapters. This is especially true on wireless systems. They probably reversed the polarity.